# how to remove file extensions from a rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having some trouble with a mod rewrite rule and was hoping someone was able to help...

I have some urls which are like `example.com/o/overview/?did=10` and I have added a rewrite rule to my htaccess that rewrites the url to `example.com/o/overview/10.php` however I do not want the .php to appear at the end and this is where I'm running into trouble.

I have tried to add another rewrite rule that removes the file extension (.php or .html) however that doesn't seem to work. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Below is the htaccess:

```
# Remove file extensions from url
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^o/overview/([^/]*)\.php$ /o/overview/?did=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules file.

***Please make sure:***

- Place your .htaccess rules file along with `o` folder(not inside it, alongside it).
- Place your .php OR .html files inside `/o/overview` folder.
- Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteBase /o/overview/

##Rules for, From url example.com/o/overview/79 to https://example.com/o/overview/index.php?did=79
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(o/overview)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/index.php?did=$2 [QSA,L]

##Rules for url example.com/o/overview/?did=10 to example.com/o/overview/10.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(o/review)/?\?did=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(o/overview)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(o/overview)/([^/]*)/?$ $1/$2.html [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I've remove my code and replaced it with your suggestion and when I visit `example.com/o/overview/10` I get a 404 error. I'm assuming the `RewriteRule ^(o/review)` should actually be `RewriteRule ^(o/overview)` (I've tried both and still it doesn't work).

Comment: @jamesstancil, sure fixed the typo now. Could you please do let know if you have placed htaccess in same place like I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: That is correct, the htaccess and o directory are both placed at the root of the domain. Here's a link to an image that shows the directory structure [link](https://ibb.co/F3WyGVh)

Comment: @jamesstancil, ok could you please do let me know what sample link you are hitting and whats happening when you hit that link?

Comment: The URL I'm typing into my browser is: `example.com/o/overview/79` and when enter is pressed a 404 page is displayed. If I was to type the original URL which is: `https://example.com/o/overview/index.php?did=79` the page shows as expected.

Comment: @jamesstancil, ok gotcha. So you want both rules: for when someone hits `example.com/o/overview/79` should be rewrite in backend to `https://example.com/o/overview/index.php?did=79` **AND** someone hits `https://example.com/o/overview/index.php?did=79` should be redirected to `example.com/o/overview/79`? can you please confirm these once.

Comment: @jamesstancil, on top of my previous comment, please do check my Updated rules now. I have updated my rules. Let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: I believe so, rather than a user typing `https://example.com/o/overview/index.php?did=79` I'd like it so they can type `https://example.com/o/overview/79` which is a lot more user friendly

Comment: @jamesstancil, Ok sure, I have written rules for both the cases please do check my updated rules and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Uploaded the updated rules and it still returns a 404 error when typing `https://example.com/o/overview/79`

Comment: @jamesstancil, could you please confirm if index.php is present in o/overview folder?

Comment: index.php is present in /o/overview/

Comment: @jamesstancil, Considering your .htaccess is present in `/root/.htaccess`(as an example), `/root/overview/index.php` is php path if this is the case then rules should work. Also one more thing do you have any other htaccess file in your system apart from this one??